# Template.templatename.rendered and template instances

Tags: meteor

Whats the best way to interact with an instance of a template? I have a gallery of html5 videos I want to play when they are scrolled into view and stopped when they are outside the browser window.

the below code works perfectly for one video, but when I have multiple videos the code changes all videos at the same time, `is_playing` is set to the exact same value for multiple videos.

these are possible related discussion but I couldn't quite figure it out: 
[Let helpers access template instance #1529](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1529), [Need way to reactively depend on data context / template arguments](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2010)

```
Template.showcaseVideo.rendered = function () {

    var video_id = this.data._id;
    var video = document.getElementById(video_id);
    var is_playing = false;

    $(window).on("scroll", '', function (event) {

        if(isScrolledIntoView($('#'+video_id)) && !is_playing) {
            video.play();
            is_playing = true;
            console.log( "playing " + video_id);
        } else if (is_playing) {
            video.pause();
            is_playing = false;
            console.log( "stopped " + video_id);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign `is_playing` variable to instance of template:

```
Template.showcaseVideo.rendered = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.is_playing = false;

    $(window).on("scroll", '', function (event) {
        var video_id   = self.data._id;
        var video      = document.getElementById(video_id);
        var is_playing = self.is_playing;
        if(isScrolledIntoView($('#'+video_id)) && !is_playing) {
            video.play();
            is_playing = true;
            console.log( "playing " + video_id);
        } else if (is_playing) {
            video.pause();
            is_playing = false;
            console.log( "stopped " + video_id);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried a few variations of `self`, and it doesn't seem to help. still stops/plays both of them at the same time 
   `[Log] stopped pAP8N573ecktbh9N2 (showcase_video.js, line 36)
   [Log] stopped NoucQ7qNgFQSZEaZM (showcase_video.js, line 36)`
`

Comment: Answer updated. Probably you need to select `HTMLElement` video inside scroll callback.